# Can I get private key in form of plain text from RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsa

I have instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider. Can I get private key in a form of plain text from this object?

Thank you.

Comment: [`RSA.ToXmlString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsa.toxmlstring(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a defined "plain-text" format for an RSA key. Calling ExportParameters will return the key parameters, and then you can turn that into text via whatever form makes sense. But note that while the RSA algorithm is defined on numbers, because the numbers are quite large the keys are usually just considered as structured byte arrays.

The ToXmlString method is one example of a string representation, using XML for delimiting Base64 encoded byte arrays.